# Terraform to call an SSM document

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-ssm

Could anyone help me here?
I'm trying to create the automation to stop ec2 instance on regular basis. I know how to use the datasource:

```
    data "aws_ssm_document" "ssm_doc" {
      name            = "AWS-StopEC2Instance"
      document_format = "JSON"
    }
```

When I try to create the association:

```
    resource "aws_ssm_association" "example" {
      name = ssm_doc
      
    
      targets {
        key    = "InstanceIds"
        values = [aws_instance.ex.id]
      }
    }
```

When I run this, I get the error:
`Error creating SSM association: ValidationException: The assume role is invalid.`

Can anyone help me and tell me how to pass the role?

Comment: isnt this `name = ssm_doc` should be soemthing like this `name = data.aws_ssm_document .ssm_doc.name` ? I am assuming you already have correct permissions.

Comment: For data.ssm_doc, you're right. It's not a complete example. I just wonder how to specify the role? Because, I don't have any way to pass it in an aws_ssm_association

Answer (score 1):

`AWS-StopEC2Instance` takes `AutomationAssumeRole` parameter. You have to provide the role for SSM to assume to execute your code. For example:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "ssm" {
  path               = "/"
  assume_role_policy = <<EOL
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": ["ec2.amazonaws.com", "ssm.amazonaws.com"]
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
EOL

  managed_policy_arns = ["arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonSSMAutomationRole"]

  inline_policy {
    name = "my_inline_policy"

    policy = jsonencode({
      Version = "2012-10-17"
      Statement = [
        {
          Action   = ["iam:PassRole"]
          Effect   = "Allow"
          Resource = "*"
        },
      ]
    })
  }
}
```

Also `targets` block in `aws_ssm_association.example` applies to SSM document types of `Command` and `Policy` or rate controlled `Automation`. For simple execution of `Automation`, `targets` is not needed:

```
resource "aws_ssm_association" "example" {

  name = "AWS-StopEC2Instance"
  
  parameters = {
      AutomationAssumeRole = aws_iam_role.ssm.arn
      instanceIds = aws_instance.ex.id
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the doc [aws_ssm_association](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ssm_association) there is no `iam role` specific configuration for this resource.  So the error might be somewhere else.

From the documentation [Troubleshooting Systems Manager Automation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/automation-troubleshooting.html#automation-trbl-access)

> Invalid assume role

> When you run an Automation, an assume role is either provided in the runbook or passed as a parameter value for the runbook. Different types of errors can occur if the assume role is not specified or configured properly.

You need to check in the `ssm_doc` you are importing, it is basically just a `cloudformation` template, so the role there you have to correct.

[Method 2: Use IAM to configure roles for Automation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/automation-permissions.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you go on the AWS module for terraform documentation, they have an example document that shows how to deploy an SSM document on a cron job with eventbridge.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Like always, the answer provided by Marcin is the best. If you follow that, don't forget to add the following lines to your Document definition under
*aws_ssm_document* resource:

`assumeRole: "{{ AutomationAssumeRole }}"`

In the IAM Role permissions also add permissions to access that resource, for example, if you want to use RDS, then add (of course you can fine-tune it):

```
      Statement = [
        {
          Action = [
            "rds:Describe*",
            "rds:Start*",
            "rds:Stop*",
            "rds:Reboot*"
          ]
          Effect   = "Allow"
          Resource = "*"
        },
      ]
```